# What does "Entangled life" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I've recently seen an article on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entangled_Life
But, I didn't get the meaning of the title, how should I understand it or what should I imagine when I hear or see "Entangled life"?

Answer (score 1):

The article says that the author of the book **Entangled life** is an expert on [mycorrhizal fungi](https://treesforlife.org.uk/into-the-forest/habitats-and-ecology/ecology/mycorrhizas/). Fungi grow a mass of threads under the surface of whatever they are growing on. He presumably intended *entangled* to be a reference to these threads.